# ¿El significado de “si" + futuro + adj + indicativo?

Tags: gramática, locuciones

> Si serán lentos en este restaurante que se enfría la comida antes de servirla.

¿Cuando se usa esta expresión?

Comment: Hausmeister, nos encantan tus preguntas y que nos inundes el sitio con ellas. Lamentablemente en este caso debemos avisarte de que no aceptamos preguntas que pidan traducciones a otros idiomas. Te podemos explicar la frase y lo que quiere decir, pero la traducción final deberás hacerla tú o solicitarla en el sitio de inglés. Por otro lado, insistimos en que deberías darnos cuantos más detalles mejor. Aquí nos gustan las preguntas largas y elaboradas. ¡Ánimo y sigue así!

Comment: @Charlie Realmente, Hausmeister33 ha motorizado el sitio con preguntas variadas e interesantes. No estoy tan de acuerdo respecto de la necesidad de que las preguntas deban ser necesariamente largas y elaboradas. A veces lo bueno y breve es dos veces bueno (en la medida en que la pregunta sea clara, obviamente), y las preguntas de Hausmeister33 en general lo son.

Answer (score 4):

El significado de la frase es aproximadamente: *"Son tan lentos en este restaurante que se enfría la comida antes de servirla."* Es una forma coloquial y bastante expresiva de transmitir esta idea.

El origen de la expresión es probablemente una elipsis: donde dice *si serán lentos...* debería decir ***imagina*** si serán lentos.... La frase invita al oyente a imaginarse una situación tan especial o inesperada o extrema que provoque el efecto que sigue después del *que*. El concepto es igual que el de *tanto... que..*.

La estructura comienza con un *si*, y el verbo de la primera parte que sigue es un tiempo futuro simple o compuesto dependiendo del verbo de la segunda parte. Al presente le corresponde futuro simple:

> *Si **serán** lentos... que se **enfría** la comida...* (fut. simple ← presente)

Al pretérito simple le corresponde el futuro compuesto:

> *Si **habrán sido** lentos... que se **enfrió** la comida...* (fut. comp. ← pretérito)

La razón de emplear un tiempo futuro es para darle expresividad. Es decir, no es un futuro real, sino que simplemente se utiliza ese tiempo verbal en esta estructura. La *Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española* (NGLE) dice ([45.14n](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SuNbHgvYfQxKIpCD)) que el condicional *si* es un "cuantificador a distancia" equivalente a "hasta tal punto" (o sea, "tanto"), y que el tiempo futuro está utilizado en su función de "futuro de conjetura". Es como si dijéramos:

> ***Hasta tal punto deben ser lentos*** en este restaurante que se enfría la comida antes de servirla.

Comment: +1 Bien explicado. Otra opción es: *Cómo serán de lentos que se enfría la comida / Cómo habrán sido de lentos que se enfrió la comida.*